# Convert TableCell text into hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching data from a sql query into an asp table in cs code behind page

```
TableCell tCell1 = new TableCell();
tCell1.Text = myDataRow["tid"].ToString();
```

I want to convert that id into a hyperlink. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a `HyperLink` control and add it as a child of the `TableCell`:

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.NavigateUrl = ...
link.Text = ...

TableCell tCell1 = new TableCell();
tCell1.Controls.Add(link);
```

Comment: Awesome... 
wow.. I am becoming zombie..brain dead :P
convert the text into link & put that link in the cell..doh..
Thanks a lot Jordao XD