# Need to set Property and open link at same time inside a TableCell

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have an `asp:Table` that is populated in the code behind with TableCells.

I started at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199430/convert-tablecell-text-into-hyperlink) and was able to set up hyperlinks to the desired page. However, I need to set a C# Property as the link is being clicked.

The first column of the Table has names, my goal was to make the names clickable links that would open a new window or tab (different URL) and pass a Property like [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx#Getting%20Public%20Property%20Values%20from%20the%20Source%20Page) (In the section : Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page) for the next page to use.

I made the property but for the life of me can't figure out how to set the property as the link is being clicked. I've tried using [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx), [Linkbutton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx), and [Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx) as well as having an HTML `a href` string placed in the cell.

I think LinkButton came the closest but it did not have a `UseSubmitBehavior` option to set to false so the link would not process.

I thought that this would be a simple process, set the property and then follow the link.

**EDIT**

Currently, have the code below, When I click the buttons nothing happens, it never enters the `link_Click` event, p.ID is what I am going to set the property to, I think I can get it from sender or e parameters somehow.

```
foreach (Person p in people)
{
                DivDetail.Visible = true;
                TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
                Table2.Rows.Add(tRow);

                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                Button link = new Button();
                link.Text = p.FullName;
                link.ToolTip = p.ID;
                link.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                link.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "link_Click");


                tCell.Controls.Add(link);
                tCell.Font.Bold = true;

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
      //other cells of row populated 
 }

void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        Response.Redirect("/Orig.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [QueryString](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) item. You can put a variable in the url that is being clicked and read that variable on the other page.

Lets say in page 1 you create the hyperlink with the url, and you want to send a variable called `myVariable` to the next page. You can add it to the link

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.NavigateUrl = "/Page2.aspx?myVariable=" + myVariable;
link.Text = "My Link";
```

Now on Page 2 you can read that query string item again into a variable for use in code behind

```
if (Request.QueryString["myVariable"] != null)
{
    string myVariable = Request.QueryString["myVariable"];
}
```

But you can also do a form post to another page, so all the form field items can be read on the other page. So you would add a LinkButton to page 1 and set it's `PostBackUrl` to page 2.

```
LinkButton linkbutton = new LinkButton();
linkbutton.PostBackUrl = "/Page2.aspx";
linkbutton.Text = "My LinkButton";
```

Now when the button is clicked you can get the posted items in code behind of page 2.

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    Response.Write(key + ": " + Request.Form[key] + "<br>");
}
```

A third option would be to do a normal PostBack on Page 1 and then set a Session and redirect to Page 2 and read the Session there.

```
LinkButton linkbutton = new LinkButton();
linkbutton.Click += Linkbutton_Click;
linkbutton.Text = "My LinkButton";


private void Linkbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["myVariable"] = myVariable;
    Response.Redirect("/Page2.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to set `SomeProperty` to `someValue` and then send the browser to `someUrl`, use a LinkButton and set its [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click(v=vs.110).aspx) even handler up like this:

```
void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeProperty = someValue;
    Response.Redirect(someUrl);
}
```

If the property value isn't available server-side, you can pass it in a hidden form variable:

```
void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeProperty = Request.Form["SomeField"];       
    Response.Redirect(someUrl);
}
```

Or, if it's a problem to set a form variable, you can set the value up using the [OnCommand Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791208/how-can-i-tell-which-button-in-a-repeater-got-pressed).  Set it this way as you bind the table:

```
protected void Table_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("MyLinkID") as LinkButton;
    lb.CommandArgument = someValue;
}
```

and read it this way:

```
void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeProperty = e.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect(someUrl);
}
```

If you need to set a property on the destination page (which would make a little more sense) you'll have to temporarily store it in session...

```
void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Temp"] = Request.Form["SomeField"];       
    Response.Redirect(someUrl);
}
```

...and then set it:

```
//This is the load event handler for the second page
public void Page_Load()
{
    this.SomeProperty = Session["Temp"];
    Session.Remove("Temp");
}
```

Comment: Link button doesn't have `UseSubmitBehavior` to set false so I can't use it unfortunately, thanks though

Comment: No problem.. You can just use a regular `asp:button` and [style it like a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214378/button-which-looks-like-link).